# VBA/Excel - Opening workbook and pasting as values on current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My code here is working fine when it opens a file and copies it to my current worksheet but I am unable to copy the data as values only. Can someone take a look?

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [RawData!A1]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xlsx),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet.UsedRange
            .Copy PasteStart
            Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
            
        End With
    Next Sheet

End If

    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `.Copy PasteStart` use the line `PasteStart.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value`.

Comment: You're welcome. Is the `ActiveWorkbook` the workbook containing this code? I would write an improvement, nothing too elaborate, to spare you some headaches in the future.